# what is the best way color store in sql

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, colors

i am not sure which is the best for   color store  in sql

i can be perform 3 way Color Name ,Hex color code , RGB Color Code. what is the datatype for the color .

please suggest me i am working a eCommerce side with Asp.net MVC and sql 2012. i need to store product color . 
[image]

Comment: what you want to do ? store product color ? if so that must be string(varchar) like "black","white","blue" ........

Comment: You want to store product colors? So would you even know the related HTML color code? Or is it rather that a product has  a color like 'raspberry red', 'checkered red and white', 'brown with gold'? Maybe you can have categories like 'red', 'white', 'brown', 'gold' and attatch one or more to each product. Maybe a main color and sub colors? Plus an additional color text that reads good? There is much to consider.

Comment: @NazmulHasan I need to store product color ! . which one for best ?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner   may be  it is not related on html color code . cause consumer not understand hex color code or RGB color code . so what should i do please suggest me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably need a color table with, say, 20 colors, the clients can use to filter the products.

Here is one rather simple database design where a product has various colors:

**table color** - these are the generic colors used for filtering

- color_id
- color_name - *e.g. 'red', a text you can use to show in the filter options*
- color_code - *e.g. #FF0000, a color you can use to show in the filter options*

**table product** - the product (irrespective of its colors)

- product_id
- product_description

**table product_color** - the product's colors; these are the items that are actually ordered

- product_id
- color_id
- color_name, *product-specific e.g. 'dark red'*
- price

(That may get more complicated when the product has various sizes, too.)

Answer (score 1):

if you are use only  0xRRGGBB format than you store in integer in database and rehexidecimal when you want to select.or how to store value in database its depend on.

Comment: IMO this is the best answer, if colors already share an id (hex code) making an id on top of them would be an overkill.
The color_id seems like a good idea only if a specific name is going to be attached to it.
But colors can be identified visually, so if no name... an int hex is the way.

Answer (score 0):

For storing color in database use input type color if you want to store colorcode in html.

And in sql save the color with a char(6) without the # if the column is not null... if the column is nullable use a varchar(6) to saving size

Comment: I need to store product color ! . which one for best ?